# Understanding ejabberd filter_packet hook parameters

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to implement a chat messaging application using Smack and ejabberd. I am getting the input below as `Packet` parameter in my filter_packet hook on my server:

```
   {{jid,<<"senderUserName">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"Smack">>,<<"senderUserName">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<"Smack">>},{jid,<<"receiverUserName">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>,<<"receiverUserName">>,<<"domain.com">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>},{<<"to">>,<<"receiverUserName@domain.com">>},{<<"id">>,<<"4Xd7d-13">>},{<<"type">>,<<"chat">>}],[{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"my message">>}]},{xmlel,<<"thread">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"25e5fc87-e57f-4046-9aef-30c569ab9160">>}]},{xmlel,<<"customTag">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"Custom extras">>}]}]}}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why I am getting sender and receiver Usernames twice ?
2. How can I get the values of different tuple elements in Erlang ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ejabberd filter_packet hook parameter is a tuple containing the following value: `{FromJID, ToJID, XMLPacket}`.

- FromJID is a `#jid{}` record.
- ToJID is a `#jid{}`.
- XMLPacket is an `#xmlel{}` record, that is a parsed representation of the original XMPP packet.

Your first question is about the `#jid{}` record structure (From and To). The internal record is not intended to be used directly but through the `jlib.erl` function. However, at the moment, the record is indeed optimized for avoiding extra processing and matching on namepreped, nodepreped username and domain. The namepreped / nodepreped value are stored as an addition to the original untouched value. If the processed values are equals to the original value, yes, you may feel this is a duplicate. However, it will be different if you are using various case and some special unicode characters.

I guess your second question is about the parsed XML element datastructure. To extract and manipulate the data from the #xmlel record, you can extract the needed field of the record: name, attrs, and children.

The record is defined as:

```
-record(xmlel, {
    name = <<"">> :: binary(),
    attrs    = [] :: [attr()],
    children = [] :: [xmlel() | cdata()] }).
```

You can use that info to get down in the XML tree, using the children list.
You will also find ready-made helper functions in the `xml.erl` module.